# How to reconnect to node.js's remote debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

In using node.js's debugger, I've been debugging by running the node process with `node --debug-brk XXXX.js`. The annoying thing is, if I ever accidentally disconnect, I have to start the process all over again. Is there a way to reconnect to the debugger? When I try (via intelliJ), it simply never reconnects.

Comment: When you reconnect, are you setting a breakpoint for it to stop on? `--debug-brk` stops at the start of the program, and since you are trying to avoid restarting it, you'll have to set a breakpoint somewhere.

Comment: yup, breakpoints were already set (since i was already debugging before accidentally closing the debugger connection)

Comment: Debugging is also kind of process which start --debug flag and starts,pauses,continues on the breakpoints, but if you say you have stopped process, how is that it will save that session? i don't think there is way of doing(else not available by now to my knowledge).

Comment: I have not stopped the process. I simply have disconnected the debugger connection.

Comment: DId you ever manage this mate? All the answers seem completely wrong imo

Comment: @JamieHutber I've been using `--debug` whenever possible these days, and I haven't had this problem in a while. Any script I start with `--debug-brk` is something I want to restart a lot anyway.

Comment: I will try with debug instead of `--inspect` then

Answer (score 2):

Try node-inspector it will reconnect to node server when you open it in browser but debugging will start from starting.

Comment: What do you mean "Start from starting"?

Comment: @BT start from starting means execution of program will start from first line

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if my server is still running, why would my debugger start from the "first line"?

Comment: @BT sorry not first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nodewebkit which makes it easy for debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

The [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) debugger released as part of the [Google Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/) can be used to debug Node.js scripts. A detailed explanation of how this works can be found in the [Node.js GitHub wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger).

**Alternatives would be**

Node.js version 0.3.4+ has built-in debugging support.

```
node debug script.js
```

Manual: http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

**Profiling with [Profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler)**

**Note**: the profiler module is deprecated, and may not work with version 0.12 of node

1. Install globally `npm install -g profiler`
2. Start your process with `node --prof` this will create a v8.log file
3. Build nprof by running `~/.nvm/v0.8.22/lib/node_modules/profiler/tools/build-nprof`
4. Run `~/.nvm/v0.8.22/lib/node_modules/profiler/nprof` this will read the v8.log profile and give you nice output.

**CPU and Memory Profiling with [NodeTime](https://nodetime.com/)**

1. Install to your application, `npm install nodetime`
2. Include in your application, `require('nodetime').profile()`
3. Follow the instructions it will output to console

Alternatively, you may want to use [look](https://github.com/baryshev/look), which is based on nodetime, but it doesn't send data to nodetime.com.

**Developer Tools Debugging with [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)**

1. Install it globally: `npm install -g node-inspector`
2. Run your application in debug mode: `node-debug your/node/program.js` (or attach to a running process: `kill -s USR1 <your node process id>)`
3. In another terminal window run node-inspector: `node-inspector`
4. Open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858` (or debug remotely by replacing 127.0.0.1 with your host; make sure port 8080 is open).

**Webkit Developer Tools Profiling with [Node Webkit Agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent)**

1. Install to your application, `npm install webkit-devtools-agent`
2. Include in your application, `agent = require('webkit-devtools-agent')`
3. Activate the agent: `kill -SIGUSR2 <your node process id>`
4. Access the agent via the [appropriate link](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent)

Comment: So most of what you're talking about is profiling, which has nothing to do with my question. Are you saying that chrome's developer tools can reconnect to a node.js script after already disconnecting once?

Comment: Are you using socket.io by any chance in your project ?

Comment: I'm not, I am using websockets tho